# Why does workbook.write(outputStream) gives ( SAX Feature unsupported) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not supported error

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, apache-poi

In a spring boot application, I am trying to use an excel template as an input, modify the contents and write the into new file using Apache POI.
This is the method code,

```
private String createExcel(String filePath, @Valid Loads loads) throws IOException {
   String excelFilePath = filePath + "Panel schedule - REV 03.xlsx";
   Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(excelFilePath));

   //also tried with XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input_document);

   Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
   Cell cell2Update = sheet.getRow(5).getCell(1);
   System.out.println("before update" + cell2Update.getNumericCellValue());
   cell2Update.setCellValue(loads.getLoadA());

   System.out.println("After update" + cell2Update.getNumericCellValue());
   input_document.close();
   // Open FileOutputStream to write updates
   String newFilePath = (filePath + "2Panel schedule - REV 03_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".xlsx");
   //FileOutputStream output_file = new FileOutputStream(new File(newFilePath));
   try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFilePath);
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        workbook.close(); --> this is where the error occuring (line 219)
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    workbook.close();
    return newFilePath;
}
```

It is giving me the error as below

```
2022-03-28 14:57:15.222  WARN 31864 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.a.p.u.XMLHelper                        : SAX Feature unsupported
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not supported: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalStylesheet
at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.setAttribute(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:571) ~[xalan-2.7.2.jar:?]
at org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper.trySet(XMLHelper.java:284) [poi-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
at org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper.getTransformerFactory(XMLHelper.java:225) [poi-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
at org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper.newTransformer(XMLHelper.java:231) [poi-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.StreamHelper.saveXmlInStream(StreamHelper.java:56) [poi-ooxml-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipContentTypeManager.saveImpl(ZipContentTypeManager.java:68) [poi-ooxml-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ContentTypeManager.save(ContentTypeManager.java:450) [poi-ooxml-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:563) [poi-ooxml-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1490) [poi-ooxml-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:227) [poi-ooxml-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
at com.fluence.springbootexample.controller.MainController.createExcel(MainController.java:219) [classes/:?]
at com.fluence.springbootexample.controller.MainController.createBottlePost(MainController.java:96) [classes/:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) [spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) [spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
```

I am getting the above error but, I am able to create a new file with modified data successfully.  I am not able to figure out the cause for this and fix it. I also tried by using XSSFWorkbook, but resulting the same.

Comment: Please check if there are multiple incompatible versions of `xalan` in the classpath.

Comment: @AxelRichter No, I am not using multiple `xalan` versions.

Comment: maybe remove xalan - the java runtime has a forked version of xalan anyway

Comment: @PJ Fanning is right. So what JRE version used here? It would must be at least version 1.8.

Comment: @PJFanning You are right. Actually, I have not mentioned `xalan`. However after @AxelRichter 's suggestion I tried with `xalan` dependency. But none of it worked. 
Also, I am using the latest Java 18. So, I think, it should not be a problem here.

Comment: There definitely is a problem with XML transformer. Try `String transformerFactoryProp = System.getProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory"); System.out.println(transformerFactoryProp);` Does it print something? What? Try `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory transformerFactory = javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(); Class transformerFactoryClass = transformerFactory.getClass(); System.out.println(transformerFactoryClass.getName());` What does it print?

Comment: @AxelRichter For `transformerFactoryProp` it printed `null` and 
`transformerFactoryClass.getName()` it printed `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl`.

Comment: Now try `String transformerFactoryPath = transformerFactoryClass.getName().replace(".", "/"); ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(); java.net.URL res = classloader.getResource(transformerFactoryPath + ".class"); String path = res.getPath(); System.out.println("TransformerFactory came from " + path);`. That prints where `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl` came from.

Comment: I suspect that comes from current used JRE. But then the error is weird if that JRE is not an ancient one. So I am also lost here.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks for the suggestions. Strangely, after I rebooted my system and invalidated the cache and restarted IntelliJ, the error went away. I don't know how and what made it work. Although I've done this cache invalidation and restarting the IDE process before also, but it didn't help before.